# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Using Doctrine 2 I want to get some users that are contacts of another user. The table `user` contains the mapping between those users. The query in the function will return the following error:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.

However to my best understanding `$str`is set to "b" and `$ownerId` is set to "2" and both are assigned by the `setParameters` function.

```
 protected function getContactBySubstring($str, $ownerId) {
        echo $str;
        echo $ownerId;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->add('select', 'u')
                ->add('from', '\Paston\VerBundle\Entity\User u, \Paston\VerBundle\Entity\Contact c')
                ->add('where', "c.owner = ?1 AND c.contact = u.id AND u.username LIKE '?2'")
                ->add('orderBy', 'u.firstname ASC, u.lastname ASC')
                ->setParameters(array (1=> $ownerId, 2=> '%'.$str.'%'));

        echo $qb->getDql();
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $users = $query->getResult();
        foreach($users as $user)
            echo $user->getUsername();
        exit;
        //return $contacts;
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't surround any of the parameters in your query text with quotes!

```
->add('where', "c.owner = ?1 AND c.contact = u.id AND u.username LIKE '?2'")
```

should be

```
->add('where', "c.owner = ?1 AND c.contact = u.id AND u.username LIKE ?2")
```

Comment: My situation is a bit different using the querybuilder. In my case I was building using $queryBuilder->where(...)->setParameters(...) but I needed to use andWhere() since I had a few where statements that were being dynamically added.